# How can I get a random value of a list of objects using custom filters?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm trying to get a single random object in a list of objects directly on my template.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

**views.py** goes like this : `Font.objects.all()`

**template file :**

```
{% for f in Fo.checkbox.all %}       #f|random_choice doesn't work here.
    <p>{{ f.font_name|random_choice }}</p>     #gives me a single random character of each object.
{% endfor %}
```

the example above gives me a single random character of each object in list, but I'm trying to get a random object in the list of object.

here is the **templatetag** file :

```
@register.filter(name='random_choice')
def random_choice(l):
    return random.choice(list(l))
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: show a little more of views.py. What are you passing to the template for context? Where does Fo.checkbox come from? If you have something like fonts=Font.objects.all() in your views, and pass it as {'fonts': fonts,} then in your template {{ fonts|random }} should work. You seem to be looping through something already. Hunch is you may want {{ Fo.checkbox.all|random }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its already built in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#random

```
{{ my_list | random }}
```

if this was for an interview and you gave any other answer than this one ... I hate to tell ya but you probably did not give the answer they were looking for...

```
{{ Fo.checkbox.all | random }}  {# print one random value from Fo.checkbox.all #}
```

Comment: I know it already exists but where should I put it to show on random result from `Fo.checkbox.all`

Comment: now I'm getting this error : `'Font' object is not iterable` why ?

Comment: try printing it ... this has now extended way beyond the scope of your question i think ...